# A problem related to row space of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix with real entries. Suppose that $\{(1, 1, 1, -1), (1, -1, 1, 1)\}$ is a basis of row space of $A$. I want to show that there is  no such $A$ with $(1, 2, 1, 4)$ in the null space of $A$?

My attempt: I know that $(1, 2, 1, 4)$ does not belong to row space of $A$ and the row space of $A$ generates the image space of $A$ as a linear transformation. So I think there should exists one such $A$. Please tell me where I am lacking?

Comment: I suppose that by "linearly independent to row space" you mean "does not belong to row *space*", and by "the row space of A generates" you mean "the row space of A is equal to". Anyway, the image is not the row space but the column space. And the fact that $(1, 2, 1, 4)$ does not belong to the former or the latter has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question slightly.

Comment: Not enough but never mind since you seem to understand the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $$r_{1}=[1,1,1,-1]\quad r_{2}=[1,-1,1,1].$$
Since $\left\{r_{1},r_{2}\right\}$ is a basis for the row space of $A$, we can write any row $R_{i}$ of $A$ as a linear combination of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$. Furthermore, $$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}R_{1}\\R_{2}\\R_{3}\\R_{4}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}.$$
This can only be the zero vector if $R_{i}[1,2,1,4]^{T}=0$ for $i=1...4$. So what you have to show is that a linear combination of $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ can never yield $0$ when multiplied with $[1,2,1,4]^{T}$, i.e.\begin{align}(c_{1}r_{1}+c_{2}r_{r})\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}&=[c_{1}+c_{2},c_{1}-c_{2},c_{1}+c_{2},-c_{1}+c_{2}]\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\4\end{bmatrix}\\
&=[1(c_{1}+c_{2}),2(c_{1}-c_{2}),1(c_{1}+c_{2}),4(-c_{1}+c_{2})]\end{align}
can never be the zero vector.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I got your idea. Thank you very much.